# How to read token balances with solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, balances

I'm using remix.ethereum. Solidity can return the ether balance of account with code like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract showBalance{
    address owner = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c;
    uint256 public showBalance = owner.balance;
}
```

If I have a token named like TESTTOKEN [TTN]
with this details

> Token Holder:   0xe780e329d218a1f849f1cab777217a2cfbb410f2
>
> ERC20 Contract: 0xf3106ff9bd5ad9a12e91d90e0ed3526111668c1c
>
> (metamask token details)

How can I get TTN balances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract ERC20 {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract MyContract {
  address tracker_0x_address = 0xf3106ff9bd5ad9a12e91d90e0ed3526111668c1c;

  function getResult() public returns (uint256) {
    // address test = msg.sender; // use this if you want to get the sender
    address test = 0xe780e329d218a1f849f1cab777217a2cfbb410f2; // hardcode the sender
    return ERC20(tracker_0x_address).balanceOf(msg.sender);
  }

}
```

Comment: tanx but it retruns me - character in decoded output

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HhOBwM7.png screen shot

Comment: You need to deploy a Token contract, and have that address set, check this code out https://gist.github.com/mickys/22d8861faa1b9267882d138ab2601d2d, in remix, deploy the "Token" contract, get it's address and then deploy MyContract, and call the "updateBalanceResult()" method with parameter "address_of_token_contract", https://pasteboard.co/HhPuyK9.png

Comment: use view with getResult() if you want to view the balance